# geolocation array with static variables

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geolocation

I have two locations (markers) to display on a google map, one is a static variable called "companyLocale".  The second is a dynamic variable based on your current location "initialLocation".  I am trying to group them into an array called "localArray" but I can't get the "companyLocale" variable to display within the array .  Can someone please help me?

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: iPhone Geolocation</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var initialLocation;
var companyLocale = new google.maps.LatLng(33.206060, -117.111951);
var localArray = [initialLocation,companyLocale];

var noGeo = new google.maps.LatLng(40.69847032728747, -73.9514422416687);

function initialize() {
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 14,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

  // Safari supports the W3C Geolocation method
  if(navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
      var placeMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: initialLocation,
        map: map,
      });
      map.setCenter(initialLocation);
    }, function() {
      handleNoGeolocation(browserSupportFlag);
    });
  } else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    handleNoGeolocation();
  }

  function handleNoGeolocation() {
    initialLocation = noGeo;
    map.setCenter(initialLocation);
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" onload="initialize()">
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're populating localArray with the two values before your initialize function gets called.  As you've already defined companyLocale as a LatLng, that one is fine, but you don't create the initialLocation LatLng until later in your execution.

I would say remove initialLocation from the array initially.  Then after you create it, add it into the array.  I don't know if the order of the array items is important here for you or not.  If it isn't, just use .push() to append it into the array.  Otherwise use unshift() to prepend it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var initialLocation;
var companyLocale = new google.maps.LatLng(33.206060, -117.111951);
var localArray = [companyLocale];

var noGeo = new google.maps.LatLng(40.69847032728747, -73.9514422416687);

function initialize() {
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 14,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

  // Safari supports the W3C Geolocation method
  if(navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);

      localArray.unshift(initialLocation);

      var placeMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: initialLocation,
        map: map,
      });
      map.setCenter(initialLocation);
    }, function() {
      handleNoGeolocation(browserSupportFlag);
    });
  } else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    handleNoGeolocation();
  }

  function handleNoGeolocation() {
    initialLocation = noGeo;
    localArray.unshift(initialLocation );
    map.setCenter(initialLocation);
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Duncan, Thank you for responding, I tried the code above, but the results haven't changed.  I still only get the initialLocation variable to display, the localArray still doesn't appear.  Can you help with this again please.

Comment: Well in the code you're not doing anything with localArray, what do you mean by "localArray still doesn't appear" - appear where/how?

Comment: I was trying to get both variables initialLocation and companyLocale in an array, and have each variable within that array display on map as markers based on their coordinates.

Comment: You don't really need the array for this.  You're already handling the marker creation for initialLocation, you just need to add similar code to create a marker at companyLocale